# How to escape HTML entities inside array in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to populate a select box with options from an array and escape those options so currency symbols lile `€` get displayed rather than `&euro;`.

How can this be done in Ruby on Rails?

This is my function:

```
def options
  array = []
  array << ["&dollar;", "some value"]
  array << ["&euro;", "some value"]
end
```

And this is the form:

```
<%= f.select(:format, f.object.options) %>
```

I tried things like `array.html_safe` but unfortunately it's not working.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot mark an array HTML safe. You need to mark *each element* within the array as HTML-safe.

Try

```
array.map(&:html_safe)
```

**Update**

Sorry, I didn't look closely enough at how you are building the array. I thought it was a flat array of strings, in which case `array.map(&:html_safe)` would have been fine. Instead, you have to do the same for each *sub*-array of strings:

```
array.map { |e| e.map(&:html_safe) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This method throws an error here, though: `undefined method 'html_safe' for ["&euro;", "some value"]:Array`. I also appended it to the select statement in the view but get the same error there. I am probably missing something trivial here since I am fairly new to Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the options array with actual symbols, rails helper will code it in html for you.

```
def options
  array = []
  array << ["$", "some value"]
  array << ["€", "some value"]
end
```